# Reference to uninitialized collection error

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace function cmp return number as

    type GyomuAuth1D is table of char(2);
    type GyomuAut2D_type is table of GyomuAuth1D;
    GyomuAut2D GyomuAut2D_type;   

begin
    for x in 1..50
    loop
        GyomuAut2D(x)(0) := null; 
    end loop;
end;
```

I am trying to assign null to first 50 places of the 2D array with for loop.
But it is showing "Reference to uninitialized collection" error
Can anyone spot what mistake i have done... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First you need to initialise `GyomuAut2D`. It is still empty though, so there is no element 1 until you extend it (otherwise you'll get `ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count`). I've chosen to `extend(50)` once for efficiency since we know how many we want, although you could also `extend` once per loop iteration.

The same applies to each `GyomuAut2D(x)` as it is also an uninitialised and empty collection.

Also the function needs to return something.

```
declare
    function cmp
        return number
    is
        type GyomuAuth1D is table of varchar2(2);
        type GyomuAut2D_type is table of GyomuAuth1D;
        GyomuAut2D GyomuAut2D_type := GyomuAut2D_type();
    begin
        GyomuAut2D.extend(50);

        for x in 1..50
        loop
            GyomuAut2D(x) := GyomuAuth1D(null);
        end loop;

        return GyomuAut2D.count;
    end;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(cmp);
end;
```